# How to create RML Report?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, rml

I'm going to create reports using my module (custom analytic account module).
I heard that RML is the easiest way to generate reports.

Please give me the required files list to create reports.
ex:-

```
__openerp__.py
__init__.py
```

------what are the other files need to create

It's easy when you mention sample module (purchase/stock) and give me file names from that,
then I can browse them and by the use of that create my own reports for my modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**_*openerp*_.py**

- for rml location

**_*init*_.py**

- for initialization of a class( import reportclass)

**.py**

- for business logic of report or methods of class which will help in rml

**.xml**

- for a menu display (where report menu open)

**.rml**

- for your structure of a report

I working with Libreoffice Writer, compare to rml, rml gives better format and accurate spacing compare to LibreOffice Writer.

for more details Visit https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports/

and configuration of a report in LibreOffice Writer Visit https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports/

and for more details use Google ;-),

Hope this will help you