# How to create Openerp Report

Tags: python, report, odoo

I have a simple module in openerp, and I need report for that module. I have searched many links but I can't get exact answer.
Here my source code.

*init*.py

```
import sim
```

*openerp_*.py

```
{
    'name': 'Student Information Management',
    'version': '0.1',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'description': """This module is for the Student Information Management.""",
    'author': 'Mr Praveen Srinivasan',
    'website': 'http://praveenlearner.wordpress.com/',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'data': ['sim_view.xml'],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
}
```

sim.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class student(osv.osv):
_name = "sim.student"
_description = "This table is for keeping personal data of student"
_columns = {
    'reg_no': fields.integer('Registration Number',size=7,required=True),
    'student_name': fields.char('Student Name',size=25,required=True),
    'father_name': fields.char("Father's Name",size=25),
    'gender':fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
    'contact_no':fields.char('Contact Number',size=10),
    'address':fields.char('Address',size=256)
}
_sql_constraints = [
('uniq_name', 'unique(reg_no)', 'This Reg.No is number already registered!') 
]

student()
```

sim_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ============== student================= -->
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_form">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Student" version="7.0">
<group>
<field name="reg_no"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
<field name="address"/>
</group>
</form>
</field>
</record>
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view end-->

<!--2nd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_tree">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<tree string="Student">
<field name="reg_no"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
<field name="address"/>
</tree>
</field>
</record>
<!--2nd part of the sim_view end-->

<!-- 3rd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_student">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="res_model">sim.student</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
<!--3rd part of the sim_view end-->

<!--4th part of the sim_view start-->
<menuitem name="SIM/Student/StudentInfo" id="menu_sim_student"  
      action="action_student"/>
<!--4th part of the sim_view end-->
</data>
</openerp>
```

This module works fine. But I don't know how to create Report for this. Please suggest any answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647902/how-to-create-rml-report/19654888#19654888 check out this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create report through sxw, rml and python code and you can also create report from aerroreport and wkhtmltopdf(Webkit report engine )

for sxw and rml please check this link this will  help you lot [Report Creation](http://sahotaparamjitsingh.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-reports-in-openerp.html)

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.10 and the openoffice report designer does not support in LibreOffice.

Comment: yes You need to downgrade your libre office version e.g if you have 4.X.X then you need to downgrade it in 3.x.X